# How to find regexp patterns in a Python list?

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list of bad word. Let's say it is:

```
BAD_WORDS = ['bw1', 'bw2',...]
```

Now I'm wondering what is the most efficient way to check a long string (aka a django request post) in a code like:

```
if re.search(comment.body) in BAD_WORDS:        
        dosomething;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use one expression for all the bad words:

```
import re
bad_words = ['bw1', 'bw2', ... ]

my_expression = '|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in bad_words)
if re.search(my_expression, comment.body):
    do_something()
```

Comment: Good answer, however, I would pass `flags=re.IGNORECASE` into re.search to account for case insensitivity.

Comment: @Rishi I'd say that would have to be up to the implementer, not suggested by the answerer. It could be that `ass` is a censored work but `ASS` is the Association for Sentimental Sapiens or etc.

Comment: @Rishi how should I add the flag?

Comment: @supermario `re.search(my_expression, comment.body, flags=re.IGNORECASE)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `any` for this.

To match only the substring not exact word you can use the `in` operator:

```
if any(word in comment.body for word in BAD_WORDS):
    #do something
```

To match exact word use `regex`:

```
import re
if any(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(word)), comment.body)
                                                            for word in BAD_WORDS):
    #do something
```